# SQL Duplicate column name error

Tags: sql

I am trying to find an error in a massive SQL statement (not mine) - I have cut a lot of it out to make it readable - even pared down it still throws the error

```
SELECT DISTINCT Profiles.ID 
FROM 
   (select * from Profiles RIGHT JOIN FriendList ON (FriendList.Profile = 15237) 
    order by LastLoggedIn DESC ) as Profiles
```

This returns an error

> Duplicate column name 'ID'

I have tested the the last part (`select * from Profiles ... order by LastLoggedIn DESC`)  and it works fine by itself

I have tried to troubleshoot by changing column names in the DISTINCT section without any luck.

One solution I read was to remove the DISTINCT, but that didn't help.

I just can't see where the duplicate column error can be coming from.  Could it be a database integrity problem?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: is there an id column in the profiles table that is conflicting with another table's id column?  You are selecting all columns, I would recommend reducing the number of columns selecting (change * to column names) and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Could it be that both the `Profiles` and the `FriendList` table in your inner `SELECT` have an `ID` column?? So you would basically have two columns, both called `ID` - and you're selecting **everything** from that `JOIN` - so which `ID` are you referring to when you say `SELECT DISTINCT Profiles.ID .....` ?!?!?

Comment: marc_s & Robert - yes, that's what is going on.  I guessed as much but this is just beyond my SQL understanding. The problem is that the SQL statement is MASSIVE and is built dynamically.  I cut it to the bare bones for this question.  I am going to toss it back to the person as the knock-on effects of messing with either this or the db are too awful to contemplate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your `Profile` and `FriendList` tables both have an `ID` column. Because you say `select *`, you're getting two columns named `ID` in the sub-select which is aliased to `Profiles`, and SQL doesn't know which one `Profiles.ID` refers to (note that `Profiles` here is referring to the alias of the sub-query, not the table of the same name).

Since you only need the ID column, you can change it to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Profiles.ID FROM 
( select Profiles.ID from Profiles RIGHT JOIN FriendList ON (FriendList.Profile = 15237) 
order by LastLoggedIn DESC ) as Profiles
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the "select *" with "select col1, col2..." and the error should become apparent (i.e. multiple columns named "ID"). Nothing to do with distinct or database integrity.

Comment: yes. but is there a way to just rename one column? My table has hundreds of columns. I do not want to type each and every one's name.

Answer (score 0):

you have a table called Profiles and you are "creating" a temp table called Profiles in your From, that would be my guess as to what is causing the problem. call your temp bananas and try `SELECT DISTINCT bananas.ID FROM` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, each of the tables that you're joining together has a column named `ID`.  You'll have to specify which `ID` column you want (`Profiles.ID` or `FriendList.ID`) or include `ID` in the join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Profiles and FriendList both have an ID column.  You are asking to call the entire join "Profiles", and then using Profiles.ID, but SQL doesn't know which ID you mean.