# Having issue with MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Getting error message [Err] 1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(all.id) 'All', 
       COUNT(unanswered.id) 'Unanswered',
       COUNT(unchecked.id) 'Unchecked'
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN courses-lessons cl ON c.id = cl.cid
INNER JOIN questions all ON cl.id = all.lid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM questions
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM answers)
) unanswered ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM questions q
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM answers
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM answer_chk_results)
    ) a ON q.id = a.qid 
) unchecked ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

What am I missing? Can't find what's wrong.

## UPDATE

Database structure

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9ExyO6ktYcOenZ1WlBwdlY2R3c

Answer (score 0):

Your questions and answers tables both have id columns. When yo do SELECT * you would be getting an id column for both. Try specifying the columns you require in the SELECT instead of using *

See here for similar question: [SQL Duplicate column name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260936/sql-duplicate-column-name-error)

Comment: Basically, get rid of every '*', replace with specific columns (and as others have said, don't use ALL as an alias)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its part of your problem or not, but you shouldn't alias a table to "all" as it is a MySQL keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely on this part of your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM answers
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM answer_chk_results)
) a ON q.id = a.qid
```

The outer query will have two fields called `id`, you should specify which `id` field you want.  Also instead of using `SELECT *` you should call out the fields you need.

`ALL` is also a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), I would consider changing that alias or use backticks `` ` `` around it.

Based on your table structure, it looks like you want:

```
SELECT c.id, 
    c.name, 
    COUNT(allq.id) 'All', 
    COUNT(unanswered.id) 'Unanswered',
    COUNT(unchecked.id) 'Unchecked'
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN courses-lessons cl 
    ON c.id = cl.cid
INNER JOIN questions allq 
    ON cl.id = allq.lid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT q.id, a.qid, q.lid
    FROM questions q
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, qid
        FROM answers
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM answer_chk_results)
    ) a 
        ON q.id = a.qid 
) unchecked 
    ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM questions
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM answers)
) unanswered 
    ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Comment: [Err] 1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'a.qid' in 'on clause'

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'a.qid' in 'field list'

Comment: @epic_syntax see my edit, these errors are telling you that you need to have the columns in your select statements.

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'allq.lid' in 'on clause'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15978/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-bluefeet)