# SQL-Duplicate column names

Tags: sql, alias, outer-join

I am using SQL developer and I am trying an outer join on two tables. The error it is showing is "Duplicate column names". I have used the table nameswhile comparison but still it is giving error. Code is as following:

```
CREATE VIEW OECD_VIEW AS
SELECT * FROM DM_OECD_GDP FULL OUTER JOIN DM_OECD_DOCTORS 
ON DM_OECD_GDP.DATA_YEAR = DM_OECD_DOCTORS.DATA_YEAR;
```

I have heard that this error can be resolved by aliasing but I don't know how to alias while comparing. Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: `create view v (c1, c2, c3, ...) as select ... `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Duplicate column name error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260936/sql-duplicate-column-name-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly name returned fields from both tables and alias fields having the same name, like:

```
CREATE VIEW OECD_VIEW AS
SELECT DM_OECD_GDP.DATA_YEAR AS GDP_DATA_YEAR,
       DM_OECD_DOCTORS.DATA_YEAR AS DOC_DATA_YEAR,
       ... rest of the fields here
FROM DM_OECD_GDP 
FULL OUTER JOIN DM_OECD_DOCTORS 
ON DM_OECD_GDP.DATA_YEAR = DM_OECD_DOCTORS.DATA_YEAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the generalised query to create views with alias and full outer join :

```
create view v6 as select t1.c1, t2.c2 from t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If both tables have same column names, may be the foreign keys, dont use * , Manually select the column names

```
table_one - ID,Name
table_two - ID,SecondName

select table_one.ID,table_one.Name,table_two.ID as ID2,
  table_two.SecondName full outer join on table_one.ID=table_two.ID
```