# Remove Duplicate column names from the subquery and fetch only the selective columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have the following MSSQL Query:

```
select
    innerqueryresult.intDoorID as DoorID,
    innerqueryresult.vchrDoorName as DoorName,
    innerqueryresult.vchrAddress as Address,
    innerqueryresult.vchrDoor as Door,
    innerqueryresult.dtmStartDate as StartDate
from
(
    Select Distinct *
    FROM ADoor dr
    left join APositionAssign pos
        on pos.intOrgLevelID = dr.intOrgLevelID
    left join APositions p
        on p.intPositionID = pos.intPositionID
    left join APositionAssign posAssign
        on posAssign.vchrDoor = dr.vchrDoor or posAssign.intOrgLevelID = dr.intOrgLevelID
    Where dr.vchrDoor = '0000140'
) innerqueryresult
```

When am executing the above query it returns:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The column 'vchrDoor' was
>   specified multiple times for 'innerqueryresult'.

Though the inner query was generated dynamically through the program, I cannot be able to get the correct alias name from the query. Is there any ways to run the query without having the knowledge of alias name.
Can anyone please suggest me the solution for it.

Comment: The solution here is to explicitly list out the columns (and tables/aliases) which you want to select.  If that inner `SELECT *` is selecting multiple columns called `vchrDoor`, then there really isn't anything you can do by wrapping with a subquery.

Comment: don't use `select distinct *`, specify the column one by one

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expext result?

Comment: You don't need the subquery and you should get rid of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9260936/3404097

Answer (score -1):

As the others posted as comments (don't know why): Don't use `SELECT *`
This is always a delicate thing since your application may break, if you add any colums.