# mysql: duplicate column name on join with subquery

Tags: mysql

I've searched a lot but I still don't get it.

Here's my sample code

```
SELECT sp.testno, sp.companyid, st.* 
FROM sponsor AS sp
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT a.sponsorempno, (CASE WHEN t.companyid IS NULL OR t.companyid = '' THEN'aa' ELSE t.companyid END) agncy, a.controlno, a.tnpl, t.* 
    FROM applicant AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        test AS t
    ON a.controlno = t.controlno 
) AS st
ON sp.testno = st.testno
```

I still returns an error:

```
#1060 - Duplicate column name 'controlno'
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: The code (=question) lacks sample data, and DDL for the tables involved.

Comment: You get two columns with the same name from different tables - `a.controlno` explicitly and `t.controlno` implicitly from `t.*`. Assign an alias to at least one of columns (for example, `... , a.controlno AS a_controlno, ...`). Or replace `ON a.controlno = t.controlno` with `USING (controlno)` - these columns will be collapsed into one with the value taken from left table (`a.controlno`).

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260936/sql-duplicate-column-name-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subselect of your join, you are selecting a.controlno and by t.* t.controlno.
You should provide an alias for one of the selected columns. In your case a.controlno. This is necessary, because the table aliases of the inner select are lost, when accessing it from the outer one.

The statement below should work, if there aren't any other duplicate column names in test and the set of used columns from applicant.

```
SELECT sp.testno, sp.companyid, st.* 
FROM sponsor AS sp
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT a.sponsorempno, (CASE WHENt.companyid IS NULL OR t.companyid = '' THEN'aa' ELSE t.companyid END) agncy, a.controlno as a_controlno, a.tnpl, t.* 
    FROM applicant AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        test AS t
    ON a.controlno = t.controlno 
) AS st
ON sp.testno = st.testno
```

Comment: it worked! thanks for this! now I understand better.